# Typo3 6.2.x Providing baseURL via Additional Configuration file (defaultTypoScript_constants)

Tags: configuration, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, base-url

I'm trying to set my base URL and other settings via the Typo3 `AdditionalConfiguration.php` File, from all what I read so far it should work like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['defaultTypoScript_constants'] = '
    shopURL = http://shop.local/
    baseURL = http://web.local/
    gaId = UA-xxxxxxxx-x
';
```

later in the TypoScript I'm setting then the `baseURL` into the config like this:
`config.baseURL = {$baseURL}`

And the `shopUrl` is later used for example to include some files like this:
`file0 = {$shopURL}folder/whatever`

Currently it seems that it doesn't matter if `{$baseURL}` or `{$shopURL}` is used in the Theme Provider or in a general Typoscript on the record. In both cases the variable seems to be not used and so my frontend ends up in this:

`<base href="{$baseURL}">`

Maybe I have a wrong processing order of things or i missing something but currently can't imagine what it could be.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Don't know the reason of the problem, anyway ... using baseurl nowadays is _de-mode_ , consider switching to `config.absRefPrefix = /` more details here https://buzz.typo3.org/people/soeren-malling/article/baseurl-is-dead-long-live-absrefprefix/

Comment: I agree with biesior. There is no reason to not use absRefPrefix. That way you don't need all the hassle with the AdditionalConfiguration.php.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to that, looks nice for the baseURL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have different settings I recommend using contexts. This blog post tells you a lot about contexts in TYPO3: http://blog.marit.ag/2014/11/03/typo3-context-verstehen-und-anwenden/.

In most of our installations we've got TypoScript settings depending on the TYPO3 context. You can easily define the context via .htaccess or via PHP. As soon as you're contexts are working, you can use conditions in TypoScript to query the current context.

```
[globalString = ENV:TYPO3_CONTEXT = Production/Local/Staging]
    config {
        # compress/ concat
        concatenateCss = 0
        concatenateJs = 0
        compressCss = 0
        compressJs = 0
    }

    plugin.tx_twgoogleanalytics.settings.debug = 2
[end]
```

Comment: this is a very good addition to that, in fact very useful for the current project where we have a problem exactly because a stange implementation of URL switching. Many thanks for sharing this knowledge